# How else could I say opposition, other team, opposing team?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How else could I say opposition, other team, opposing team? For example, *I showed the opposition our pitch*. You can also say *the other team were shown our pitch*. Similarly you could phrase it, *the opposing team*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts, so that we do not reduplicate effort. For example, checking *opposing* in a thesaurus might return terms like the *contending* team, *rival team*, or *opposite team*, or the term you are probably looking for which is *opponent*. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Most idiomatic here IMO would be 'I showed the visitors / visiting team our pitch' (context of course would disambiguate, as _visitors_ could also mean tourists etc wanting to look round). Not totally synonymous, of course.

Comment: "away team" is also a common term used in  sports.  https://www.google.com/search?q=home+and+away+scoreboard&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjziPnjxsLbAhXNk1kKHZ-yAeQQ_AUICygC&biw=1529&bih=945#imgrc=Pxsl5wzWASYWDM:

Comment: Is that pitch as in playing field or sales pitch?  If it’s sales pitch then you might call them “***the competition***”

Comment: A Hockey pitch but that’s irrelevant. It’s the actual word I wish to change as I have used it roughly ten times in one paragraph. Thesauruses gave unsatisfactory answers hence my post here.

Comment: "Opponents" would be reasonably idiomatic in the US.

Answer (score 0):

a **competitor**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/competitor) 'a competing team'

> One that competes with another, as in sports or business; a rival.